# SDWebImage load image then receive memory warning and crash

Tags: ios, crash, sdwebimage, memory-warning

I use SDWebImage in my app. I have several UIImageView in my viewcontroller, and
   all of them use setImageWithURL: method(in UIImageView+WebCache.m)
   load image by URL. There are three images should be load, two images
   about 520kb, and the little one is 180kb. While I do run it , it will
   receive memory warning and crash, I have no idea about it. Can anyone
   help me, thanks!

Here is my code:

```
    NSDictionary    *data = [respDic objectForKey:@"data"];

    [self.topLeft setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[data valueForKey:@"tr_cu_1"]]];
    [self.bottomLeft setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[data valueForKey:@"tr_cu_2"]]];
    [self.bottomRight setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[data valueForKey:@"tr_cu_3"]]];
```

Comment: Please use another method or stop loading image and then tell me what happen to you

Comment: What's another method? And I need these image, why do you suggest me stop loading image ???

Comment: just for checking that only SDWebImage is creating problem or not?

Comment: In my test project, I Only use SDWebImage load the three image, it also cause this problem, but If I dont' have a lot of app in background, it will not. And, if I don't use SDWebImage in my app, and only use three imageview load the three image from my local bundle, it also receive memory waring. Images are too big?

Comment: It is not creating problem at my side

Comment: I think there is problem at your coding part.Please test if you are not loading image then problem persist or not?

Comment: Oh, thanks for your help. I test these on my Ipad mini which would cause memory warning, and it will be ok if i test on simulator. If I don't load images it will not cause memory warning, I think it's my images are too big or because my device has small memory.

Comment: OK are you loading all three images at same time?

Comment: Yes, I load three images just like the code I wrote in one method. Is that cause my problem.

Comment: May be load one one image at a time and see the response